# Should we use survey::svyglm() to compute correct standard errors with WeightThem?

Tags: r, weights, survey-weights

I need to use multiply imputed datasets and weights before using linear models (linear, logistic and negative binomial).

I have 2 sources of informations that point to different directions to compute correct standard errors, and cannot decide which to follow :

1. In the [`WeighIt` article "Estimating effects"](https://ngreifer.github.io/WeightIt/articles/estimating-effects.html), it is written that we should "avoid using {survey}"
2. The [`MatchThem` documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MatchThem/vignettes/vignette.pdf) recommends "for generalized linear outcome models, the svyglm() function in the `survey` package should be used as it correctly accounts for the weights and produces approximately correct standard errors."

Even more confusing is [Noah's blog post](https://ngreifer.github.io/blog/treatment-effects-mi/) who goes by a third way.

Could any of you help by explaining the correct way to compute standard errors for multiply imputed datasets using weights, and explain the statistical point ?

Best regards,